# Jest - mocking a class function from an external node module

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

I am writing unit tests for a NestJS service, which imports and instantiates a class (OAuth2Client) from an external module (google-auth-library) and uses one of its functions (verifyIdToken).

I am mocking the class to override that function as follows:

```
// service.test.ts

jest.mock('google-auth-library', () => {
  return {
    OAuth2Client: jest.fn(),
  };
});
import { OAuth2Client } from 'google-auth-library';

describe('test', () => {
  it ('test1', () => {
    OAuth2Client.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        verifyIdToken: () => true
      }
    });
  });

  it('test2', () => {
    OAuth2Client.mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        verifyIdToken: () => false
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This works correctly and the test passes, but I am seeing a Typescript error saying that mockImplementation does not exist on OAuth2Client and am wondering if this approach is the best way to achieve what I want or is there an alternative. I was reading around and saw that an option is to use `jest.spyOn` as well.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! When you state "_but I am seeing a Typescript error saying that mockImplementation does not exist on OAuth2Client_" is that an error that shows in an IDE, the test output, or elsewhere?

Comment: It shows in the IDE and its produced by the Typescript extension (I'm using VS Code). The tests pass normally regardless, I'm just mostly wondering whether my approach is considered good practice.